# i have the end result of a shell script in echo and i want to convert it to json object

Tags: python, json, shell, jq

i got this end results of a long shell script i want to convert it to a json object is there's any simple way where i can pipe the echo | in to it

```
echo "name=$get_name
pass=$get_pass
value=$get_value
key=$get_key
port=$get_port
server_ip=$get_ip" | jq
```

i want to get this results like this json

```
     {
      "pass": "$get_pass"
       "value": "$get_value"
       "key": "$get_key"
        "port": "$get_port"
        "server_ip": "$get_ip"
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'name=$get_name
pass=$get_pass
value=$get_value
key=$get_key
port=$get_port
server_ip=$get_ip' | jq -Rs '
  split("\n")
  | map(capture("(?<k>^[^=]*)=(?<v>.*)")  | {(.k): .v} )
  | add'
```

produces output in the format you've indicated you want:

```
{
  "name": "$get_name",
  "pass": "$get_pass",
  "value": "$get_value",
  "key": "$get_key",
  "port": "$get_port",
  "server_ip": "$get_ip"
}
```

Obviously if you wanted $get_name to be evaluated at `echo` time, you'd use double-quotes.

Comment: as the content of echo has variables i replaced the single quote ' with double quotation " , it worked fine